# Logstash installing plugin error

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

Good day:

I'm trying to install a plugin `logstash-output-json_batch` on Logstash however, I'm getting this error:

```
C:\Program Files\logstash\logstash-6.3.1\bin>logstash-plugin.bat install logstash-output-json_batch
Validating logstash-output-json_batch
Installing logstash-output-json_batch
Plugin version conflict, aborting
ERROR: Installation Aborted, message: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "logstash-core-plugin-api":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    logstash-core-plugin-api (= 2.1.16)

  In Gemfile:
    logstash-devutils (= 1.3.5) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 2.0) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-codec-netflow (< 4.0.0, >= 3.14.1) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (~> 2.0) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-filter-dissect (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 2.1.1) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-input-s3 (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 2.1.12) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-file (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (< 2.99, >= 2.0.0) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-stdout (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (< 2.99, >= 1.60.1) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-webhdfs (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (<= 2.99, >= 1.60) java

    logstash-output-json_batch (>= 0) java depends on
      logstash-core-plugin-api (~> 1.0) java

    logstash-core-plugin-api (>= 0) java
```

The purpose of using this event is to batch my events over to *http* instead of singular calls (which is the case for `http` plugin).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The bundler doesn't find compatible version,
First way is, you can download repository and modify "gemfile" and install it manualy
Second way is, update bundler.